# How should I fix these garbage values?

Tags: c, memory-management, garbage

I am an apprentice of C language, trying to learn some stuff here.
I had confronted with a problem, and I wish I could have solved it on my own.
But, I am a short wrapper and quite prone to procrastination, so I need your good support.
As the title explicitly says, I do not know why my topMatches() function is spitting out some random float values, printing out at the beginning and the end of an array of scores[].
Like this,

```
Output #1
(-0.00000, Lisa Rose),(0.99124, Gene Seymour),(0.92447, Michael Phillips),(0.89341, Claudia Puig),(0.66285, Mick LaSalle),(0.38125, Jack Matthews),(-1.00000, Toby)
Output #2
(107185664961793568883398204719104.00000, Lisa Rose),(0.99124, Gene Seymour),(0.92447, Michael Phillips),(0.89341, Claudia Puig),(0.66285, Mick LaSalle),(0.38125, Jack Matthews),(-1.00000, Toby)
Output #3
(0.99124, Lisa Rose),(0.92447, Gene Seymour),(0.89341, Michael Phillips),(0.66285, Claudia Puig),(0.38125, Mick LaSalle),(-118195603315995709432961818167345152.00000, Jack Matthews),(-1.00000, Toby)
...
```

The value should be in the range of -1 and 1.
I would really appreciate to see your feedback.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

//data types
struct mInfo
{
    char mName[20];
    float rating;
};
struct cInfo
{
    char name[20];
    struct mInfo movi[7];
};
//prototype fxns
typedef double (*sim_fp)(struct cInfo *, const char *, const char *);
double sim_D(struct cInfo *prefs, const char *person1, const char *person2);
void topMatches(sim_fp fp, struct cInfo *prefs, const char *person1, int num);
int cmpFxn (const void * a, const void * b);
void reverseFxn(float arr[], int num);

int main() 
{
    int num = 7;
    struct cInfo critics[num];
  
    critics[0] = (struct cInfo) {"Lisa Rose", {"Lady in the Water", 2.5, "Snakes on a Plane", 3.5, "Just My Luck", 3, "Superman Returns", 3.5, "The Night Listener", 3, "You, Me and Dupree", 2.5}};
    
    critics[1] = (struct cInfo) {"Gene Seymour",{"Lady in the Water", 3, "Snakes on a Plane", 3.5, "Just My Luck", 1.5, "Superman Returns", 5, "The Night Listener", 3, "You, Me and Dupree", 3.5}};
    
    critics[2] = (struct cInfo) {"Michael Phillips",{"Lady in the Water", 2.5, "Snakes on a Plane", 3, "Superman Returns", 3.5, "The Night Listener", 4}};
    
    critics[3] = (struct cInfo) {"Claudia Puig",{"Snakes on a Plane", 3.5, "Just My Luck", 3, "Superman Returns", 4, "The Night Listener", 4.5, "You, Me and Dupree", 2.5}};
    
    critics[4] = (struct cInfo) {"Mick LaSalle",{"Lady in the Water", 3, "Snakes on a Plane", 4, "Just My Luck", 2, "Superman Returns", 3, "The Night Listener", 3, "You, Me and Dupree", 2}};
    
    critics[5] = (struct cInfo) {"Jack Matthews",{"Lady in the Water", 3, "Snakes on a Plane", 4, "Superman Returns", 5, "You, Me and Dupree", 3.5}};
    
    critics[6] = (struct cInfo) {"Toby",{"Snakes on a Plane", 4.5, "Superman Returns", 4, "You, Me and Dupree",1}};
    
    topMatches(sim_D, critics, "Toby", 7);

    return 0;
}

double sim_D(struct cInfo *prefs, const char *person1, const char *person2)
{
    int i=0;
    int x=0;
    int next=0;
    int p1;
    int p2;
    float X = 0;
    float Y = 0;
    float sumSq1 = 0;
    float sumSq2 = 0;
    float pSum = 0;
    float num = 0;
    float den = 0;
    float Pscore = 0;
    int nElements =0;
    
    
    for (i=0;i<7;i++) {
        if(strcmp(prefs[i].name, person1) ==0)
        {
           p1 = i; 
        }
        else if(strcmp(prefs[i].name, person2) ==0)
        {
            p2 = i;
        }
    }
  
    for (x=0;x<7;x++) {
        for (next=0;next<7;next++) 
        {
            if (!prefs[p1].movi[x].rating && !prefs[p2].movi[next].rating);
            else if (strcmp(prefs[p1].movi[x].mName, prefs[p2].movi[next].mName) == 0)
            {
                  X += prefs[p1].movi[x].rating;
                  Y += prefs[p2].movi[next].rating;
                  sumSq1 += pow(prefs[p1].movi[x].rating,2);
                  sumSq2 += pow(prefs[p2].movi[next].rating,2);
                  pSum += (prefs[p1].movi[x].rating*prefs[p2].movi[next].rating); 
                  nElements++;
            }
        }
        next = 0;
    }
  
    num = pSum-(X*Y/nElements);

    den=sqrt((sumSq1-pow(X,2)/nElements)*(sumSq2-pow(Y,2)/nElements));
    if(den ==0) return -1;

    Pscore = num/den; 

    return Pscore;
}

void topMatches(sim_fp fp, struct cInfo *prefs, const char *person1, int num)
{
    float scores[8];
    char *buf;
    int i=0;

    for (i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(person1, prefs[i].name)==0)
        {
          continue;
        }
        scores[i] = fp(prefs, person1, prefs[i].name);
    }
  
  qsort(scores, num, sizeof(float), (*cmpFxn));
  reverseFxn(scores, num);
   printf("\n\n");
        for(i=0;i<num;i++)
        {
          if (i == num-1)
          {
            printf("(%.5f, %s)", scores[num-1], prefs[num-1].name);
          }
          else
          {
            printf("(%.5f, %s),", scores[i], prefs[i].name);
          }
        }
}
void reverseFxn(float arr[], int num)
{
  float scoresTmp[num];
  int j;
        
    for(j=0;j<num;j++)
    {
      scoresTmp[num-1-j] = arr[j];
    }
      for(j=0;j<num;j++)
      {
        arr[j]=scoresTmp[j];
      }
}
int cmpFxn (const void * a, const void * b) 
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

The value of each elements of the scores[] array needs to be within the range of -1 and 1.

Comment: I'd start by stepping through the code in a debugger to see where the problem happens. For a start you might consider why you're quicksorting an array of floats with a comparison function that assume the bits passed in are ints.

Comment: Saucdp, Why use `float` yet with `double` functions?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Oof does that mean that since the size of float and double are different to each other in which results memory fault during the interaction in between the  return data type of the function (double) and the data type of the array(float). And this is where the problem is occurring?

Comment: @Saucdp Seems a bit unfair to ask [more questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75131539/how-should-i-fix-these-garbage-values?noredirect=1#comment132606118_75131539) without addressing an earlier [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75131539/how-should-i-fix-these-garbage-values?noredirect=1#comment132585414_75131539).

Answer (score 0):

1. Unexpected variable output is a hint that uninitialized data is being used.  In `struct cInfo` you have a member `struct mInfo movi[7];` but assign between 3 and 6 of these in `main()`.  By switching from assignment to initialization those records that are not explicit set will be zero initialized.  This seems to be sufficient to get consistent output.

```
int main() {
    struct cInfo critics[] = {
        {"Lisa Rose", {
            {"Lady in the Water", 2.5},
            {"Snakes on a Plane", 3.5},
            {"Just My Luck", 3},
            {"Superman Returns", 3.5},
            {"The Night Listener", 3},
            {"You, Me and Dupree", 2.5}
        }},
        {"Gene Seymour", {
            {"Lady in the Water", 3},
            {"Snakes on a Plane", 3.5},
            {"Just My Luck", 1.5},
            {"Superman Returns", 5},
            {"The Night Listener", 3},
            {"You, Me and Dupree", 3.5}
        }},
        {"Michael Phillips", {
            {"Lady in the Water", 2.5},
            {"Snakes on a Plane", 3},
            {"Superman Returns", 3.5},
            {"The Night Listener", 4}
        }},
        {"Claudia Puig", {
            {"Snakes on a Plane", 3.5},
            {"Just My Luck", 3},
            {"Superman Returns", 4},
            {"The Night Listener", 4.5},
            {"You, Me and Dupree", 2.5}
        }},
        {"Mick LaSalle", {
            {"Lady in the Water", 3},
            {"Snakes on a Plane", 4},
            {"Just My Luck", 2},
            {"Superman Returns", 3},
            {"The Night Listener", 3},
            {"You, Me and Dupree", 2}
        }},
        {"Jack Matthews", {
            {"Lady in the Water", 3},
            {"Snakes on a Plane", 4},
            {"Superman Returns", 5},
            {"You, Me and Dupree", 3.5}
        }},
        {"Toby", {
            {"Snakes on a Plane", 4.5},
            {"Superman Returns", 4},
            {"You, Me and Dupree",1}
        }}
    };
    topMatches(sim_D, critics, "Toby", sizeof critics / sizeof *critics);
}
```

and here is example output:

```
(0.99124, Lisa Rose),(0.92447, Gene Seymour),(0.89341, Michael Phillips),(0.66285, Claudia Puig),(0.38125, Mick LaSalle),(0.00000, Jack Matthews),(-1.00000, Toby)
```

2. (not fixed) Consider rewriting the unusual if expression with an empty body:

```
if (!prefs[p1].movi[x].rating && !prefs[p2].movi[next].rating);
else if (strcmp(prefs[p1].movi[x].mName, prefs[p2].movi[next].mName) == 0) {
```

to:

```
if (
   (prefs[p1].movi[x].rating || prefs[p2].movi[next].rating) && 
   !strcmp(prefs[p1].movi[x].mName, prefs[p2].movi[next].mName)
) {
```

If you introduce a couple of vanity variables it could be written a more compactly.

3. Replace `float` with `double` and fix the sort function:

```
int cmpFxn (const void * a, const void * b) {
    double a2 = *(double *) a;
    double b2 = *(double *) b;
    if(a2 < b2) return -1;
    if(a2 > b2) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

4. valgrind reports use of uninitialized data in topMatches specially `double scores[8];`.  You only iterate over `num` which  is `7`, and you don't set scores[i] for the entry that corresponds  to person1 so I suggest you do:

```
    double scores[num];
    memset(scores, 0, sizeof(scores));
```

5. (not fixed) Audit your code for magic values, like 7 and 20.  Use constants, pass in an argument or `sizeof a / sizeof *a` if you need the size of an array (be careful arrays degrade to pointers when passed as arguments).

Comment: Hello, I had tried and changed the struct using your initialization code. It does give me more consistent outputs, but the score values of Lisa Rose and Jack Matthews are still inconsistent sometimes. What would be the problem?

Comment: @Saucdp Sorry, I am not able to reproduce your observation.  Every run returns the same result for me.  After replacing all float with double the result would vary till I also fixed the sort function.

Answer (score 0):

At least these issues:

**Wrong compare function**

`qsort()` is called with an array of `float` and `cmpFxn`, yet `cmpFxn()` compares `int`.  <sup>*1</sup>

Need to cast to `float`.   <sup>*2</sup>

```
// return (*(int*)a - *(int*)b )
return (*(float*)a > *(float*)b ) - (*(float*)a < *(float*)b );
```

No **not** use `return (*(float*)a - *(float*)b )` as the `float` difference may overflow `int` range or truncate to 0.

**Code risks `sqrt(some_negative)`**

Watch out for slight floating point artifacts that result in a negative that mathematically should never be less than 0.

```
// den=sqrt((sumSq1-pow(X,2)/nElements)*(sumSq2-pow(Y,2)/nElements));
t = (sumSq1-pow(X,2)/nElements)*(sumSq2-pow(Y,2)/nElements);
den = t >= 0.0 ? sqrt(t) : 0;
```

**`float` vs. `double`**

Code is casual about mixing `float` and `double` objects and functions.  Suggest `double` only.

For *debug* purposes, easy enough to use `#define float double` to temporarily do this.

---

<sup>*1</sup>
`cmpFxn()` is also a weak compare function for `int` too as it risks `int` overflow.

```
// return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
return (*(int*)a > *(int*)b ) - (*(int*)a < *(int*)b );
```

<sup>*2</sup>
If not-a-numbers are involved, the compare is more complicated.  Let us assume, for now, that is not the case.

Comment: Also compare function that uses subtraction may overflow/underflow.

Comment: @AllanWind Yes, compare function, as is, is not even a good `int` one.

Comment: I wrote an implementation above, but I wanted to ask you, usually with floating point values equal is implemented as `fabs(a - b) < delta`.  Would you do something similar for the compare function?  It feels wrong if they were not sorted due to minor delta differences.

Comment: @AllanWind Rather than doing that, I'd probably use integral values. When it comes to sorting, floating-point values have already problems with NANs, while I think to remember that `qsort` requires [total ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) to produce stable results.

Comment: @Bob__ Stability is non-issue in this particular use case as far as I can tell.

Comment: @AllanWind With `qsort`, without NaNs, your `cmpFxn()` is fine.  Comparing with a `delta` will not work as that loses total ordering.